# What kind of filter would be appropriate for detecting cracks on the soil in OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, filtering, contour

My task is to count the total area of cracks on the soil surface. Here are some examples of possible input images:

img1

[image]

img2

[image]

img3

[image]

img4

[image]

I could easily detect the soil surface:

[image: Only Soil]

However, it is complicated for me to detect the cracks accurately. After a lot of research, I decided to use the Bilateral filter in combination with Canny Edges in order to detect the cracks. here is my code:

```
  blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 5, 60, 40)
  canny_cracks = cv2.Canny(blur, 100, 200)

  # Morphological Transformation for closing edges 
  kernel = np.ones((val, val))
  res = cv2.morphologyEx(canny_cracks, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

  cv2.imshow('Result', res)
```

[image: Output]

However, it is not so accurate as I expect. My question is what kind of filter and thresholding would be the best choice in order to more accurately detect the cracks? I tried to use `cv2.findContours` instead of `cv2.Canny`, it brings a lot of noise. I am sorry for such a specific question, I am new in OpenCV.

Comment: No visual recognition is ever going to be perfect. Cracks are typically long and skinny, so it would seem to me you could do quite a lot with thresholding based on object dimensions, aspect ratio, and perimeter vs area. A training set of images with pre-labeled cracks (and non-cracks) should help set these thresholds.

Comment: The soil itself is already quite noisy and contains a lot of dark spots, that almost every trivial algorithm would see as 'micro-cracks'. If you really want a good result, you might consider creating a large example dataset and then train a [pix2pix](https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/) model with it. But that does require some time and background knowledge, so have fun :)